# android SQL IllegalStateException

Tags: android

I try to use `EditText` to save database in `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

When i add the values on the function , it throws `IllegalStateException` on my `execSQL` function.

I don't have any idea about it, any help will be grateful.

it's my create database code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL("CREATE TABLE blood " +
                "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "bloodvalue VARCHAR , " +
                "eattime VARCHAR, " +
                "blooddate DATETIME NOT NULL)");
    }
```

it's my add button function:

```
sendBlood = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBlood);
        sendBlood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String bloodSugar = editBloodSugar.getText().toString();
                String bloodEatTime = editBloodEatTime.getText().toString();
                int bloodDate = Integer.parseInt(editBloodDate.getText().toString());

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("bloodvalue", bloodSugar);
                values.put("eattime", bloodEatTime);
                values.put("blooddate", bloodDate);
                long id = sqlForBloodSugar.getWritableDatabase().insert("blood", null, values);
                Log.d("ADD", id + "");
            }
        });
```

Comment: stacktrace please

Comment: i got the solution , thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL()` instead of `getWritableDatabase().execSQL()`

Comment: You are welcome. Not shame to not know, shame to not ask